# How Convert Android Date to Linux TimeStamp?

Tags: android, datetime

i have a date string in

> DD-MM-YYYY (28-11-2011)

I want to convert it into linux time stamp without time or time is zero.

I am doing it by

```
String dateString="13-09-2011";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
              Date date = null;
              try {
                    date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateString);
                    Log.v(Constants.LOGGING_TAG, "Date is " + dateString);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.v(Constants.LOGGING_TAG, "Today is " + date.getTime());
```

but this is not giving the desired result. Any body have any idea to solve this issue.

Comment: "not giving the desired result" isn't very precise. Please tell us what you're getting and what you expected.

Comment: i provide the dateString = 28-11-2011 and it gives me 1322420400000. When i reconvert 1322420400000 to date, i got Sun, 27 Nov 2011 19:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what the problem is as you haven't told us what you expected and what you're getting, but I suspect there are two potential problems:

- You haven't specified a time zone, so the formatter will parse the value in the system local  time zone. If you want a date only, you should probably set the formatter to UTC first:

  ```
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  ```
- If you want a Unix time value (in seconds), you'll need to divide the value in `Date` by 1000, as `java.util.Date` is represented in milliseconds:

  ```
  long seconds = date.getTime() / 1000;
  ```

I'd also thoroughly recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in classes for date/time manipulation.

Comment: +1 for the Joda-Time link, thanks Jon - why the heck haven't I found that before?!? Coming from Smalltalk to Java (long, long ago), I've always complained about how silly and unintuitive the Java Date implementation is.